# Google reCAPTCHA image and response field disappear IE7

Tags: recaptcha

I have the Google recaptcha displayed on a long form via the reCAPTCHA AJAX API. In IE8 Compatability mode/IE7 *only*, the CAPTCHA image and text field disappear when I select an option from any of the selectboxes on my page. Has anyone else encountered this? It's not really working to create a JSFiddle with all the external scripts and stuff. I was hoping someone had seen this.

My page has the same basic structure as the [reCAPTCHA AJAX example](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax), only with way more fields and with jquery-validate.

I am also using jquery-validate on the page as well as some other javascript, but nothing explicitly that runs when I change the value of selectboxes.

Comment: i have similair problem. `https://gateway.spectrumasa.com:10443/about/press-events/subscribe-to-news` on ie7 nothing appears